# Creating a dataframe instead of downlowding from API call

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, anaplan-api

The following python code snippet downloads a file in chunks from an API call to Anaplan. It works fine as it creates a `.CSV` file which is saved to my local drive. However, I need it to create a Pandas DataFrame instead of a `.CSV` file.

```
with open(f'{fileName}'+'.csv', 'wb') as f:
    for i in f2:
        chunkData = i
        chunkID = i['id']
        print(f'Getting chunk {chunkID}')
        getChunk = requests.get(url + f'/{chunkID}',
                                headers=downloadHeaders)
        f.write(getChunk.content)
        print('Status code: ' + str(getChunk.status_code))
```

Comment: What does `getChunk.content` look like.

Comment: Why not use the code as is and then use Pandas to open the csv file and generate the dataframe?